# How to stop AWS Cognito from sending all user attributes in JWT

Tags: jwt, amazon-cognito

I'm JWT (JSON web tokens) from AWS cognito on the frontend, and sending them to my server to verify the actions of the request.

However, the payload of the JWT contains all the user attributes of the user from cognito like address, phone number, ect. Since all that data is **not** encrypted and is just base64 text, I only want to send the username over to the server and nothing more. How do I prevent AWS from giving my frontend all the user attributes in the payload of the JWT that I don't want to be sending around in plaintext to the server. Thanks

JWT payload with all user attributes:
[image: JWT payload]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your User Pool settings, select App Client and click on **Show Details** under the app client that you are using.
Now scroll down to the very bottom of the page and click on **Set attribute read and write permissions**

[image]

Here you can select only the attributes that you want to make avaiable in your ID Token by selecting the Readable Attributes.

Comment: Ok, This is a working solution, but deselecting those attributes from the read list not only removes them from my JWT token, but also to my application when I call the user. What I wanted was a way to prevent sending those attributes in just the JWT token. All those attributes don't need to be sent to the back to the server, only the identifying attribute the server needs. I just don't know why cognito sends a token with all those attributes that the backend won't use.

Comment: What do you mean it removes it from application when you call the user? What are you using to call user?

Comment: You can also use a Pre Token Generation Lambda Trigger to forcefully supress attributed you do not want the front end to see. https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html

Comment: That works, but now I have to pay money and use resources every time a JWT is created. Cognito costs money and it should be doing that for me. I don't understand what the logic is of sending all of users attributes like adress/phone number ect which are in plain text and not encrypted to the server, when all I need is a UUID attribute on the server side. Adding a lambda will also make my app slower. I want attributes in the frontend that I don't want in the JWT token and there should be a better way to do this from AWS.

Comment: I still don't understand why removing them from readable attributes isn't an option for you. " but also to my application when I call the user" what do you mean by this?

Comment: again, I want to read those attributes attributes in my frontend. Lets say I set an address as a user attribute. I want my frontend to use the address and display it to my user, it's part of my app. However, There is no reason to send my user's address to the server every time they make a request. best practice says data inside JWT's are not to contain sensitive data, It's not secure. There is a big difference between wanting an attribute in the frontend, and wanting it in the jwt token. Removing those attributes from the readable list does not allow my frontend to see those attributes.

Comment: I already have adopted a pretoken generation lambda to solve my problem. That way I can read user attributes in my frontend and exclude them from my JWT's which are sent back to my server for validation. AWS actually addresses my concern in their reinvent video. https://youtu.be/QDR-pX7Ho8k?t=833 . What I meant by "calling the user" is the user object returned by aws with the attributes.